# an undefined error in a simple python code- KeyError: '284882215'

Tags: python

I'm getting this: `KeyError: '284882215'`. I
couldn't find anything via google/on StackOverflow; can some one assist?

Cheers!

```
ios_clean = [] 
ios_already_added = [] 

for app in ios: 
    name = app[0]  
    n_reviews = float(app[5])
    print (n_reviews)
    if n_reviews == reviews_max[name] and name not in ios_already_added: 
        ios_clean.append(app)
        ios_already_added.append(name) 
print (ios_clean)
print (len(ios_already_added))

KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-e59f5982da23> in <module>
     11     n_reviews = float(app[5])
     12     print (n_reviews)
---> 13     if n_reviews == reviews_max[name] and name not in ios_already_added:
     14         ios_clean.append(app)
     15         ios_already_added.append(name)

KeyError: '284882215'
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you're trying to access an item in reviews_max with the key "284882215", and it does not exist.

As a solution, you can use Dict get() to safely lookup a key.

```
if n_reviews == reviews_max.get(name) and name not in ios_already_added:
```

Answer (score 0):

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) says:

> exception KeyError
>   Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys.

Meaning you tried to access a key which doesn't exist.

You can use the get() method which will either return the value found OR a default value, if you want to bypass the KeyError. This is the standard method for handling a use case like yours.

```
dict.get(key, default = None)
```